# Automorphisms of B_n

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Consider the Coxeter group of type $B_n$. This group, of order $2^n n!$, can be identified with the group of odd permutations of the set $\{\pm 1,\dots,\pm n\}$ and is thus isomorphic to the permutational wreath product $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})\wr S_n$. It it true that all automorphisms of $B_n$ are inner? or otherwise how the group of outer automorphisms can be described?

[I'm working on a proof for graph isomorphism involving a Poset diagram. If all automorphisms for $B_n$ are inner automorphisms, then my proof will be complete. The proof already works for the Coxeter group of type $A_{n-1}$, namely $S_n, n\neq 6$, because all its automorphisms are inner.]

Comment: What is $B_n $?

Comment: $B_n$ is the group of reflections represented by permutations of the type (-n,-n+1,...-1,1,...,n-1,n). See Dynkin Diagrams (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram)

Comment: This question should probably be asked on stackexchange.com rather than here.   Assuming you are dealing with simple Lie algebras over a field such as $\mathbb{C}$, the automorphisms are well known and are all inner if there is no graph automorphism (as in type $B_n$).

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Humphreys. I am dealing with finite simple Lie algebras, particularly, the twisted conjugacy classes of the Weyl groups that represent them. I have finished with $S_n$, and am now working with $B_n$.

Comment: Experiments for small $n$ indicate that for $n$ even the outer automorphism group of $C_2\wr S_n$ is isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$, for odd $n$ it is isomorphic to $C_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $B_n=C_2\wr S_n$ be generated by $a=(1,2)$ (as generators of $C_2$), $b=(1,3,5,7..,2n-1)(2,4,6,..2n)$ and $c=(1,3)(2,4)$ (as generators of the $S_n$ complement. Then the map fixing $a$ and $b$, and mapping $c$ to $cz$, $z=(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)...(n-1,n)$ being the nontrivial element of $Z(G)$ is an (outer) automorphism of order $2$.

If $n$ is even the normal subgroup $C_2^n\lhd G$ is isomorphic to its dual module and this gives rise to another outer automorphism of $G$. (Together with the other automorphism given the structure of the outer automorphism group is $C_2\times C_2$.)

This seems to be all, but I have not proven this but only checked with GAP for $n\le 10$.